# Rails app won't send emails in production mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, production, actionmailer, production-environment

Hey, I'm using Rails 2.3.5 and using rufus scheduler to send periodic emails. This works fine in development mode, but *surprise surprise* production mode has borked something. I've set the same actionmailer settings in both development and production files. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Is your production server setup correctly to send mail?

Comment: Have you checked if the problem is with your SMTP server? Is that accepting connections from that server or not. Typically the dev and prod setting of the SMTP servers will be different so that you don't accidentally send mails out in dev environment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hey, yes you're right i think. The settings were set to access the server as if it was external. By that I mean I changed options like the address to localhost and commenting out others. Check it out:

```
:address => "localhost", 
:port => 25, 
:domain => "www.mydomain.co.uk", 
#:authentication => :login, 
#:user_name => "blah", 
#:password => "blah"
```

Hope this helps somebody else.

Comment: If this is working, then please accept your own solution so it leaves the list of unanswered questions :)